# How are struct mem in C?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why isn't sizeof for a struct equal to the sum of sizeof of each member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119123/why-isnt-sizeof-for-a-struct-equal-to-the-sum-of-sizeof-of-each-member)

I can't understand struct mem alloc.

```
typedef struct a{
} a;

sizeof(a) is 0

typedef struct b{
    int bb
} b;

sizeof(b) is 4

typedef struct b2{
    int *bbbb
} b2;

sizeof(b2) is 8

typedef struct d{
    int x;
    int *y;
} d;

sizeof(d) is 16!
```

Why sizeof is 16?Is it 12?(int+int point=4+8);

I guess sizeof(int) is 4,if int var in struct,mem is 8?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119123/why-isnt-sizeof-for-a-struct-equal-to-the-sum-of-sizeof-of-each-member

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why sizeof is 16?Is it 12?(int+int point=4+8);

Since the pointer is 8 bytes wide on your machine, the compiler felt obliged to align it to an 8 byte boundary, for performance reasons. On some architectures it may not even be strictly a performance problem: unaligned access to certain types can be outright illegal.

In other words the compiler is allowed to add padding everywhere, **except before the first element of the structure**.

Comment: I understand!then struct must is 8byte multiple?

Comment: thank your answer.I understand your mean.this is Machine-dependent.

Comment: @SamPeng It can also be compiler-dependent.

Comment: yes,I find this wiki [Data structure alignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment) through your help.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what platform you are on, `sizeof(int *)` could be 4 or 8 (or other).  Also, your compiler has the freedom to add unused padding bytes to the struct if it wants to.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to padding and memory alignment. Refer to [this link](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/archives/9705) for further explanations.

Answer (score 0):

Memory aligment is at work. Things need to be aligned.